# How can I write function / alias definitions into Bash history?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Let's say I have a function:

```
lsm(){
    ls ~/music
}
```

Then, let's say I ran it:

```
lsm
```

After, if I were to press the "Up" key, then I will see `lsm`: the last command I ran.

However, I'm aiming to get the Bash history write the full, expanded definition of the function/alias.

So if I were to press "Up", I will see `ls ~/music` in the Bash history after only typing `lsm` earlier.

Comment: How about is the function ran into tens of lines. Would the history make any sense then?

Comment: Add `history -s 'ls ~/music'` to your function?

Comment: @EdHeal, yes I wouldn't mind that. However, Bash tends to convert multiline code into single line after I run it, (ex. \n is converted to ;) so maybe that may also be the case.

Comment: There are two settings related to that: `shopt -s cmdhist` saves multi-line commands as a single history entry, and `shopt -s lithist` keeps the linebreaks. As for expanding before saving into history, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: Why would a long line of code be helpful in the history? Would you repeat its use when you cannot be sure that it is what you think it does (i.e. multiple functions containing many lines)

Comment: @BenjaminW., that's great to learn, glad to know this was brought up in this discussion.

Comment: @EdHeal, this is for my .bashrc file, it will personally benefit my from time to time. Most of my custom .bashrc functions are not that complex where it's detrimental to have a long command.

Comment: @EdHeal It's useful if you have, say, a three line sed or awk command which you'd like to edit as a whole; or sometimes, I write little loops across multiple lines in an interactive session, and then it's handy to have them as one history entry if there was a typo or the like.

Comment: Why is the name of the function such a problem? Would that be more meaningful than a long (ish) string

Comment: @EdHeal, looking at my example, let's say I want to modify it just one tiny bit to `ls ~/music/rock`.   I will have to type it all out from the beginning now, instead of using a handy function, assuming it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cyrus has a practical suggestion:

Use `history -s some string` to write `some string` into your history.

> ```
> history
>
> -s
>     The *args* are added to the end of the history list as a single entry.
> ```

(Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Builtins.html)

Comment: Very neat, would you happen to know how I can have this run for every command I manually input in a terminal window? At least for a function or alias that's found in .bashrc

Comment: It's not a very automatic solution, I realize, but you could add the desired command into your function definition.